# issue with double quotes when removing punctuations from a string in python

Tags: python, string, parsing, methods, punctuation

im giving this as the string to be changed-
line=''' For example, if you are computing the average of a list of numbers, you
could check that the result is not greater than the largest element in the list
or less than the smallest. This is called a “sanity check” because it detects
results that are “completely illogical”.'''

and using the following code-
import string
out = line.translate(line.maketrans("", "", string.punctuation))

the output I get is-
' For example if you are computing the average of a list of numbers you\ncould check that the result is not greater than the largest element in the list\nor less than the smallest This is called a “sanity check” because it detects\nresults that are “completely illogical”'

The double quotes are still there. How to remove double quotes as well?

Comment: They're not Ascii quotes; look at them closely. You'll see that there are two different characters, Unicode 201C and 201D, often called typographic, curly or "smart" quotes.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure exactly what the translate functions do to strings, never really played with them.. but if all you're trying to accomplish is removing double quotes then:

`line.replace('"','')`

this will replace all double quotes in the sentence with nothing, effectively deleting them.